# Using the ZFC axioms, is {1} = 2?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking at the power set of two, $P(2)$ = {$\emptyset$,  {$\emptyset$},  {1}, {$\emptyset$, 1} } = {0, 1, {1} ,2}.

I consider {1} = {{0}}.  By the Empty Set Axiom and the Subset Axiom, this set includes the empty set, ie 0 $\in$ {1}. So, I can write {1} = {{0}} as {0, {0}} = {0, 1} = 2. This would mean the power set of two only has three distinct elements.

I am using ZFC Axioms.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for the comments.  I realise that my confusion was in how I was thinking about the Subset Axiom - not distinguishing "includes as an element" from "includes as a subset".

The question is maybe kind of ridiculous.  I am not sure if I should delete it or leave it.  I would be happy if a mod wants to delete it.

Comment: Is $\{1\} = \{\{0\}\}$? Isn't $1$ the successor of $0$, that is $\{0, \{0\}\}$?

Comment: Consider the powerset of $\{a,b\}$.  You have $\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.  Now, replacing $a$ by $\emptyset$ and $b$ by $\{\emptyset\}$ we have $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ has four elements.

Comment: Note that $\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ are all different and nonequal.  You say you count only three distinct elements after rewriting/simplification... which two elements did you think were equal and why?

Comment: "*By the empty set axiom and the inclusion axiom, this set* **includes** *the empty set, ie $0\in\{1\}$*"  Includes as a subset... yes.  You do have that $0\subseteq\{1\}$.  Includes as an element?  No.  $0\not\in \{1\}$.  Recognize that the word "includes" is used in different ways depending on context.

Comment: What exactly is the "inclusion axiom"? This isn't one of the usual ZFC axioms. At a guess I suspect you have in mind "$\emptyset\in x$ for all $x$" when in fact it should be "$\emptyset\subseteq x$ for all $x$," but I'm not sure.

Comment: Apologies, I refer to the Subset Axiom.  I am new to this and it is confusing at first.  I am going to delete the question shortly because I don't think it adds value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0:=\emptyset$, $1:=\{\emptyset\}$, so that $ \{1\}:=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

We do have $0\in1$ as well as $0\subset1$ and $0\subset\{1\}$, but $0\notin\{1\}.$